# load 3 url inside my page using iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to show 3 urls inside my page  with this code as you can see here:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>A simple frameset document</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<FRAMESET cols="20%, 80%">
  <FRAMESET rows="100, 200">
      <FRAME src="http://www.asriran.ir">
      <FRAME src="http://www.google.com">
  </FRAMESET>
  <FRAME src="http://www.yahoo.com">

</FRAMESET>
</HTML>
```

But when i run my page just one url is loaded why ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i install google chrome and iframeallow extension .after that every thing works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The pages you are trying to load i.e. Yahoo and Google do not allow that by their X-frame-options.

So, it is virtually impossible now.

Note:
HTML5 has depreciated the use of frameset and frame tags. Browsers like Google Chrome (which are widely used) are switching completely to HTML5. So if possible, do not use framesets

Comment: Thank you .so could you please give me in detail?if you have any idea other than frameset?

Answer (score 0):

Some web servers are preventing iframes for a security purpose. So, you can"t open it in the frame